# Django queryset for user

Tags: django

models.py(shrunk to things that matter)

```
class Messages(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name='sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(Profile,related_name='receiver',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

forms.py

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=4096, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    class Meta:
        model = Messages
        fields = ('receiver','subject','text',)
```

I have a dropdown that shows all users that were made I would like to filter it based off some fields like is_active to showcase only users that are authenticated and more like this so I would like to override I think it's receiver queryset.

```
def index(request):

    sendMessageForm = MessageForm()


if is_staff:
   if is_active:
else:
```

What my current form displays.

```
<select name="receiver" required="" id="id_receiver">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="39">1</option>

  <option value="40">2</option>

  <option value="41">3</option>

  <option value="42">4</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Hi, you need to pass filter parameters on request if the parameters of filter change, i can think two ways of doing this, the first one is to reload the page each time you make the request to pass parameters through get request, you can make this with ajax on html script tag, the second way is to make the request with ajax like the first one, but reload just the piece of the page you need to change after ajax request, this option makes the page more dynamic but it's more difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the queryset of the field in the init of the form like so:

```
class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    text = forms.CharField(max_length=4096, required=True, help_text='Required.')
    class Meta:
        model = Messages
        fields = ('receiver','subject','text',)

    def __init__(self, *args, user=None, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')  # use this for your filter
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['receiver'].queryset = Profile.objects.filter(...)
```

Therefore updating the available choices in the drop down when the form is rendered.

Maybe on your profile you have a friends list, which is a M2M to itself, and you want to filter only user profiles which are on the senders friend list. This would be a use case for the above code.

You can also explicitly declare the field like so:

```
receiver = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Profile.objects.filter(...))
```

Note: using this method you would not be able to use request.user so this would not be valid for you.

And as per your comment, to allow you to access request.user within the init funtion:

```
def index(request):
    sendMessageForm = MessageForm(user=request.user)
```

As an added bonus, we always use snake case for variables in python. So your variable should be `send_message_form` and furthermore, if its the only form on the page, why not just shorten that variable to `form` ?

Comment: Is there a way to check in the init to be based off the request.user(currently logged in) cause I need additional fields like is_staff to filter it differently. Say I have an admin display all if user display all doctors/admin, and so forth.

Comment: Yes, you can add the kwarg. Will edit answer

Comment: Check the edits

Comment: Ok will add and accept the answer when I can.

Comment: Getting a key error.

Comment: Because you haven't added user=request.user my friend

Comment: I added some extra code to your index function

Comment: user = kwargs.pop('user', None)  seems to work

Comment: and adding sendMessageForm = MessageForm(sender=request.user) fixes it.